# For my subclass of RMMarker in Route-Me, how do I disable user interaction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, calayer, route-me

I have a subclass of RMMarker which I want don't want receiving touches. It receives touches that markers behind need to receive. RMMarkers aren't UIViews, they're based on CALayers and the hit testing is done in RMMApView. The only way I've thought of that seems like it will work is to change the hit test in RMMapView touchesEnded:withEvent, but I'm not even sure that would work, and it requires a nasty violation of modularity. There's probably an easy way to do this that would involve overriding a method on RMMarker, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite this method on the subclass of a CALayer, and an instance of this subclass can't be clicked on.

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)thePoint
{
    return nil;
}
```